# How do you calculate the Block Hash for the Current Block in Hyperledger Fabric with javascript?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I see that there has been [a utility created for the Java SDK](https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/9635/2/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdk/helper/ChainUtils.java) to calculate the hash of the current block, but do not see this implementation in the Node SDK.  I would really appreciate it if someone could give an example implementation in javascript.

I would like a javascript function that converts a decoded [Block object](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/global.html#Block) to a Byte Array.  This Byte Array is the parameter for the `Channel.queryBlockByHash(block, target, useAdmin)` method [linked here](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Channel.html#queryBlockByHash__anchor).

So for example, if I have a decoded Block object -

```
let blockObj = { header:
   { number: '100',
     previous_hash: 
'99478ca59eb60cc968cec9dde401ce70b1e470aeab4a458ba870f4a717b2e24a',
     data_hash: 
'1bee34054bc4457f51e3c00bfa552878503deb3220f2d171b55d2a35299afdb0' },
  data: { data: [ [Array], [Array] ] },
  metadata: { metadata: [ [Array], [Array], [Array] ] } }
```

I want a function like so:

```
function blockObjToByteArray(blockObj) {
  // Do ASN1 conversion here

  // Return ByteArray that can be used as a parameter
  // for the queryBlockByHash() method 
  return byteArrayBlock;
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51674154/396949. You need to pass the `header` to the `calculateBlockHash` function. It will do the rest of the work.