# how to display current hash,previous hash using node js on view pages for hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to traverse blockchain like the linked list.
I am finding only previous hash from the block by provided block no., how to get the current hash of a block using node js and I'm interested to display on view pages.

Comment: Please insert the code you have tried into your question

Answer (score 6):

The node sdk does not provide the current hash but can calculate it from the block's header using code similar to this.

```
var sha = require('js-sha256');
var asn = require('asn1.js');
var calculateBlockHash = function(header) {
  let headerAsn = asn.define('headerAsn', function() {
    this.seq().obj(
      this.key('Number').int(),
      this.key('PreviousHash').octstr(),
     this.key('DataHash').octstr()
   );
 });

  let output = headerAsn.encode({
      Number: parseInt(header.number),
      PreviousHash: Buffer.from(header.previous_hash, 'hex'),
      DataHash: Buffer.from(header.data_hash, 'hex')
    }, 'der');
  let hash = sha.sha256(output);
  return hash;
};
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: is there a method for golang ?